# wpf change foreground of labels in listview causes error

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, label

So my Code is producing Errors but it is working like intendet. I have a listview with an Label inside and a style that Targets all Labels. In this style is a Datatrigger that changes the foreground if an enum is changed.

The foreground Color is changed if i Change the state of the enum but on my console I get one error for each listview item (but only if I Change the enum from Default to Dark):

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=self'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.WindowStyleProp; DataItem=null; target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

Note: I only have one window and it is named "self".

Here is my Code for the Listview:

```
 <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="ItemView" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="134">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label BorderThickness="0" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

and this is the style Code in my application.resources:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.WindowStyleProp, ElementName=self, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static enum:WindowStylesEnum.Dark}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.WindowStyleProp, ElementName=self, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static enum:WindowStylesEnum.Default}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Besides that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the DataTrigger Bindings is pointless (because it only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Binding), it looks odd that you bind to `ElementName=self`. Which element is `self` here? You would usually just bind like `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WindowStyleProp}">`.

Comment: self is my main window and in this model is the WindowStyleProp.

Comment: If I just say 'Binding="{Binding WindowStyleProp}"' my bindings are broken and the Color doesnt Change.

Comment: Sure, the naming was just confusing. What if you replace `Element=self` with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}`?

Comment: RelativeSource with AncestorType={x:Type Window} won't work because this style is in application resources. IMO what you could try is TemplatedParent or override the style in place of it's usage and just setup datatriggers.

Comment: would it work if I move everything to window.resources ?